# Script is not working in WordPress site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I was creating a WordPress theme using a Bootstrap template. While creating it the scripts are not working in WordPress theme.

I added the script files in the `functions.php` file using the `wp_enqueue_script`. And I inspect it using the `firebug` the script files are loaded in the `footer`. But the script functions are not working (like slider,carousel,etc..,) in the theme.

Here is my `functions.php` code

```
function royaal_enqueue(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_2.1.4', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),true); 
wp_enqueue_script('move-top', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/move-top.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/easing.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('wmuSlider', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.wmuSlider.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.flexslider.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('easyResponsiveTabs', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('devrama', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.devrama.slider-0.9.4.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('lightCarousel', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.light-carousel.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
wp_enqueue_script('jzBox', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jzBox.js', array( 'jquery'),true);
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'royaal_enqueue', 999 );
```

Here is the GitHub link for the code

https://github.com/prashanthcraft/wordpress

Comment: check in firebug or chrome tool and see what error are you getting

Comment: thanks man "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
})(jQuery);"

Comment: looks like you have your script tag called before the jQuery script is called, if you share the link it would be easier to fix.

Comment: wp_enqueue_script('jquery_2.1.4', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),false); replaca with above the code

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/prashanthcraft/wordpress

Comment: @vel Thanks, It's not working still as it is

Comment: Try to add jquery in head : wp_enqueue_script('jquery_2.1.4', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),true, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 
function royaal_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_2.1.4', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js',array( 'jquery'),true);   
    wp_enqueue_script('move-top', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/move-top.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/easing.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('wmuSlider', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.wmuSlider.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.flexslider.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easyResponsiveTabs', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('devrama', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.devrama.slider-0.9.4.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('lightCarousel', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.light-carousel.js', '','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jzBox', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jzBox.js', '','',true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'royaal_enqueue',999 );

function royaal_custom_js_setting() { ?> 

    <script> 

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $(".scroll").click(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000); 
        }); 
        }); 

        //Page active Jquery 
        $(function(){ 
            var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1); 
            $(".nav li a").each(function(){ 
            if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '') 
                $(this).parent().addClass("active"); 
            }) 
        }); 

        <!-- FlexSlider --> 
        $(window).load(function(){ 
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({ 
                animation: "slide", 
                start: function(slider){ 
                    $('body').removeClass('loading'); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 

        $('.example1').wmuSlider(); 


        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' }); 
        }); 
    </script> 

<?php } 
    add_action('wp_footer','royaal_custom_js_setting'); 
?>
```

Comment: thanks, script is loading to the page but the functions are not working

Comment: this site on live server or localhost?

Comment: this site is in localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120663/discussion-between-vel-and-prashanth).

Comment: updated answer as per private chats. above the script is working fine.